# iPhone SDK: How to get 4.0 on a device?

Tags: iphone

This is a question about installing 4.0 on an 3rd gen iPod Touch. I already have a developer account. I have also downloaded the 4.0 SDK with XCode. I can test the new functionality in the simulator but I want to also try it on my device hence my question. I am looking for instructions on how to get it on my new third gen iPod Touch. Could someone suggest a link that has worked well for them? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the iPhone portal there is a section entitled: iPhone OS Beta. There you can download the OS for the appropriate device. This appears once you accept the updated agreement, etc.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action#prerelease

Comment: I have downloaded the file. iPod3,1_4.0_8A230m_Restore.ipsw. I don't know what to do it. When I click on it, nothing appears to happen. How can I get it installed on the device?

Comment: Actually this is the info I needed.

http://raven-seo-tools.com/blog/2829/how-to-install-iphone-firmware-112-on-itunes